# Is a paragraph starting with "She nervously peered over the edge." a placeholder text, or something else?

Tags: quote-source

Is a paragraph starting with "She nervously peered over the edge." a placeholder text, or something else?

> She nervously peered over the edge. She understood in her mind that the view was supposed to be beautiful,but all she felt was fear. There had always been something about heights that disturbed her, and now she could feel the full force of this unease. She reluctantly crept a little closer with the encouragement of her friends as the fear continued to build. She couldn't help but feel that something horrible was about to happen.

I first saw it in this [video](https://youtu.be/o9gQBGk1XaE?t=499), and Google searches imply that it came from some educational text, but is it really? If so, which one, and when?

Answer (score 2):

User jukesalot on [Github](https://github.com/Bouke/docx-mailmerge/issues/86) says that it comes from a 'random paragraph generator', possibly like [this one](https://randomwordgenerator.com/paragraph.php) The actual paragraph quoted in the OP's question seems to be popular among coders, web site designers, etc, who want a paragraph of test text that looks a bit more natural than [Lorem Ipsum](https://www.lipsum.com/). It seems to be often used during testing of web sites. It often shows up in Google searches even where the actual page has been developed and the dummy text removed. This is probably due to Google caching text. I have also seen it on sites that seem to have been created and never developed.

[Update] I have found an amusing thing: a random Hemingway paragraph generator called [HemingwayLorem](https://hexdocs.pm/hemingway_lorem/HemingwayLorem.html)! It seems to be something you add to code you are writing, rather than a website
Example:

> "Gee it’s awful when they go by you and then you have to watch them go
> farther away and get smaller and smaller and then all bunched up on
> the turns and then come around towards into the stretch and you feel
> like swearing and goddaming worse and worse"

Comment: Ah. A few runs of "https://randomwordgenerator.com/paragraph.php" discovered the "She wanted rainbow hair. That's what she told the hairdresser." example I've seen a few times in my previous search. Trying to pin down the code myself to see if it gives any credits.

Comment: The quality of writing seems to be universally dismal. I found this gem: "They look so funny when they lay on top of each other and sleep."